# C++ constructor and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, constructor

There is a statement in the *foudations of Qt Development* book that goes as follows:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const string& test, QObject *parent) : QObject( parent )
```

What is meant when we put `: QObject( parent )`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that there aren't two constructor declarations? The `: QObject(parent)` is an initializer list; it is initializing the base class `QObject` with the `QObject::QObject(QObject*)` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

> When you create a QObject with another object as parent, it's added to the parent's children() list, and is deleted when the parent is.

[Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html)

Answer (score 0):

In short this means that `MyClass` inherits properties (and methods) from `QObject`

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/

http://www.anyexample.com/programming/cplusplus/cplusplus_inheritance_example.xml

So `MyClass` is a `QObject`